# Kendo UI and simultaneous ajax requests in Internet Expolorer

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik-mvc

I have a page generated by Telerik MVC with a grid with popup editor. There are few ComboBoxes in the grid editor dynamically loading data from the server, in 5 ajax requests. Everything works fine in Firefox, IE and Edge, but in the Internet explorer requests takes quite long time and 3 of the requests are repeated. The result is, related ComboBoxes are not bound to its values and displays only the value without related ComboBox item assigned.

Firefox network activity:
[image]

Internet Explorer (red square are repeated requests):
[image]

I have tried to extend ajax timeout, but without effect. What is the proper solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by downgrading the Telerik MVC (and all related script/style files) from 2019.1.220.545 back to 2017.1.223.545. I have not tested any version between yet.

**Edit:**

Version 2018.2 is the last one working as expected.